# Disable Recent Task App Button when another Application launched in Android

Tags: android

I'm using this code to disable my Recent Task App Button from my app:

```
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if (!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```

It really works perfectly! However, basically, my application is a content manager of installed applications that the user wants to launch only. And when the user already launch another application and click on the Recent Task App Button, the button is already enable. How can I make it disable again?

I'm using this code to launch another application for my app...

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.sampleapp");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: As you (as a third party developer) are not supposed to interfere with system behavior, it's a rather unfortunate bug if this works in the slightest.  Expect tricks like this to be disabled in future releases.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. I'm sorry

Comment: You should not be trying to prevent the user from using the system's recent tasks menu.

Comment: But how about in SureLock Kiosk Lockdown? All the buttons are disable except Home Button when running another applciation..

Comment: The same goes for SureLock Kiosk Lockdown: "You are not supposed to interfere with system behavior,"

Comment: So does it mean that, I'm not going to disable the Recent Apps Button even if it is our client's requirement?